# How to use a compiled TypeScript class in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, tsc, tsconfig

Imagine I have this simple TypeScript class, `Animal.ts`:

```
export default class Animal {
  constructor(public name : string) { }
}
```

With this `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": true
  },
  "files": [
    "Animal"
  ]
}
```

How can I use the compiled version of this class (compiled by running `tsc`) in a javascript file like so:

```
var Animal = require("./Animal");

var newAnimal = new Animal();
```

Should I edit something in my `tsconfig.json` file? The error I get is:

> ReferenceError: Animal is not defined

Comment: You can have typescript compile javascript files as well using 'allowJs' (in tsconfig.json). That way, you can reference typescript classes from your javascript.

Comment: Since you are using default export, I do believe you have to require it like `var Animal = require("./Animal").default` <-- note the `.default` at the end.

Comment: Exporting with `export default` makes your export an module. It would become `new Animal.default('name')`. However the error is not reproducible, the Animal is exported as `{ __esModule: true, default: [Function: Animal] }`.

Comment: @ShanevandenBogaard, and how should I edit the code to use `new Animal("name")` instead of `new Animal.default("name")`?

Comment: You can do what `CRice` said or omit the `default` keyword

Comment: If I omit the `default` keyword, I still would have to use `var Animal = require("./Animal"); var newAnimal = new Animal.Animal("test");` instead of just `new Animal("test")`. How can I change it to do so? (without using `require("./Animal").default`)

Comment: Yes, sorry I just noticed that. I have been using Babel which also exports it using `module.exports = ...`. You can do `const { Animal } = require('./animal');`.

Comment: That worked! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As [Shane van den Bogaard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4515408/shane-van-den-bogaard) pointed out, the `default` keyword in `Animal.ts` needs to be omitted and :

```
const { Animal } = require('./Animal');
```

should be used instead of

```
var Animal = require('./Animal');
```

This way we can call the `Animal` class and initialize an object by using

```
const { Animal } = require('./Animal');
var newAnimal = new Animal("Clifford");
```